# CRON executing PHP file can't see included class

Tags: php, cron

I "live" on shared hosting and although they have CRON, I'm not getting much help from there. I've added a simple to-file logging in the script to see which line causes my CRON to not run.

The script runs fine when called directly in browser.

This is the structure of the root:

```
- /
  - public_html
    - cron-1500.php
    - Dev
      - Client
        - core 
          - class.php
        - other
          - cron
            - test.php
```

My hosting provider needs the actual cron file to be in `public_html` and be called with the time of the desired execution. Inside that file I have the following:

```
system("wget --delete-after http://<server>/Dev/Client/other/cron/test.php");
```

in the `test.php` I want to include a class from the `core` folder and tried the following:

```php
include_once("../../core/class.php");
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."core/class.php");
include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."core/class.php");
```

Unfortunately nothing works. I added `file_exists` and even if that returns `true` (it returns true for the first example above), the include statment still fails. Not sure if the problem is some kind of context in which CRON works or just my class' path?

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` just returns `/` in the script

Comment: How exactly did you determine that it was the include that failed? And that the error was not caused by something else later on?

Comment: _"Not sure if the problem is some kind of context in which CRON works"_ - a "proper" cron would rather call PHP from the command line, and for that usually a different php.ini gets used. But yours here isn't such a proper one, it just makes an HTTP request (via wget), so this should use the same settings, as anything else you request via the web server. Which also means, your script should most likely also not work, when you try and call `http://<server>/Dev/Client/other/cron/test.php` in your browser directly.

Comment: @CBroe I only left two lines of code. An include and the code that instantiates the class object. Then I put a line to write to file in between each file. Surprisingly, for the "../.." version I do get line "after include" but I can't imagine there would be something wrong with the class call? it's simple `new <namespace>\Class();`

The script definitely worked if I call it from the browser, that's the most annoying part. It does fail now saying the "../.." file can't be included, even though `file_exists` shows true. I'll try again

Comment: I left "../.." version and it definitely fails at include stage. My "log" file only includes "before include" line but not "after include"

Comment: _"The script definitely worked if I call it from the browser"_ - using the same URL, as you did in the cronjob? Because there is little difference between the `wget` request made there, and a request made directly from your browser - so those should behave the same to begin with.

Comment: Actually I lied (unintentionally). I called the script in the browser using a subdomain that replaces `<server>/Dev/Client` with `dev.mysite.com`. If I call it exactly like in the cron script I do get the error.

in this case I totally don't understand why "../../" is not working

Comment: I think I solved it with `dirname(__FILE__, 2)` I didn't quite understand the __FILE__ or __DIR__ but I think I do now and I added those things in files that could be included, to "reset" their position and things seem to work